# Cancelling displaying a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# do stuff here

fig = ax = None
del(fig, ax)

plt.show()
```

The `None` and `del` lines do not prevent the figure from showing. Is there any way to once I've created it? Is the only way to avoid showing a figure not creating it in the first place?

Comment: `plt.close(fig)`?

Comment: Don't call `plt.show()` at the end if you don't want the plot to be rendered and displayed on the screen. Also, instead of showing it to the user, you can silently save it to a png file using `plt.savefig('output.png')` instead of using `plt.show()`.

Comment: Maybe they want to show other windows with `plt.show`. Not every application is based on exactly one figure.

Comment: @Dilawar not calling ```plt.show()``` does not hide the plot. Mr. T's solution works.